# XNA Game crashes on computers with XNA Redistributable 4.0 Refresh, but runs with XNA Game Studio 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, xna

I've created a game in XNA and I'm attempting to run it on other computers. It works fine if Visual Studio and XNA Studio 4.0 are installed, but otherwise the game won't even open.

If I just copy the Release folder over and try to run the executable, nothing happens. No crashes, no reports, no windows.

If I install the game using an installation package I made the game will "stop working" immediately and reference three files:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\WERA006.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml    
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\WERB674.tmp.appcompat.txt    
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\WERB6E2.tmp.mdmp
```

I've opened these up and found nothing all that useful in them. The installation package works fine on my computer.

The other computers that I've tried it on have had the XNA Redistributable 4.0 Refresh installed, and I've gotten smaller XNA projects to work on them...just not this one. I use XMLSerialization and a StorageContainer, but I don't see why those would be an issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Attach a debugger or process dumper to get some information about the exception.

Comment: serialization has dependencies with culture, some cultures use ',' as decimal separator, and you will get execptions  converting float numbers

Answer (score 0):

Firstly prove that its your program and not bad installs. Compile any of the XNA samples and then copy the release folder across. If it runs then the redist is good and its something in your code.

So you are probably calling something that isn't in the redist e.g. Any XNA networking functions, any Content Pipeline stuff other than Load<> - all of those things are only in the developer tools. Or its nothing to do with XNA and there's another dependency you forgot.

Add a top level handler like this [How to implement top level exception handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616759/how-to-implement-top-level-exception-handling) and write the exception/stack trace to a file.

There's an FAQ we wrote here that might help http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/1988.aspx