# Resharper and the C# Catch Clause

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, try-catch

I'm new to Resharper and I'm trying to understand why it seems to suggest:
`catch (Exception) {   }`
`for`
`catch {   }`

and

`catch {   }`
`for`
`catch (Exception) {   }`

I'm baffled.

Answer (score 9):

Basically it's offering you a way of switching between the two alternatives, rather than making a concrete recommendation of which is better.

You can change what's offered under ReSharper / Options / Code Inspection / Inspection Severity - find the relevant option and change the priority between none, hint, suggestion, warning or error.

Answer (score 4):

Resharper does have another message that is more of a recommendation: it advises you not to catch the `Exception` class.

Comment: Why? this is exactly the functionality I want.

Comment: @BunnyStrider - you want to catch `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @DanielEarwicker No, I have to call code that sometimes throws an Exception (of type Exception, unfortunately) and if it does then I don't care.  So in this particular example I legitimately want to catch Exception and do nothing.

Comment: So the code you're calling is horrendous. It may be throwing an exception you want to catch, or it may have a bug where it tried to call a method on a null reference. In effect, Resharper is advising you not to call that code! It's good advice.

Answer (score 2):

`catch { }`  <-- supresses all errors.  we should do, only if we are sure to discard any error.

`catch { throw; }`     <--   This is not required.   It is already taken care by compiler to rethrow the error to calling function.  It is not required to add explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

It's just giving you alternatives to consider, which may spark some insight into improving your code.  Just ignore the suggestion if it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -2):

Because sometimes when tidying catch blocks you move to/from `catch(Exception ex)` to `catch(Exception)` to `catch` and vice versa, depending on whether you're trying to purely filter, log/wrap, or swallow the exception.  (See [me requesting the same feature for CodeRush without being aware it even existed in R#](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S131074.aspx))

[IIRC there may also be a difference between the two from the point of view of the code they generate/things they filter and miss](http://blogs.msdn.com/clrteam/archive/2009/02/19/why-catch-exception-empty-catch-is-bad.aspx)

EDIT: The link was previously labelled "Empty catch is bad" hence very correct downvotes!

Comment: While that maybe true, but according to the OP, Resharper is suggesting to use catch{} if you use catch{Exception}

Comment: catch() { ... } is not "an Empty Catch", it is just alt syntax for "catch(Exception) { ...} " the code inside braces does not have to be empty.. .You can (should) put code inside the braces.  If not, then it IS evil as you are swallowing generic Exception...

Comment: It's actually pretty evil whatever code you put in the braces.

Comment: Not if it's at the absolute top stackframe of a thread. Do you not think it's useful to log an exception before the whole process falls over, for example? (There's nothing to say that part of the ... isn't "throw;")

Comment: Mea culpa - didnt actually follow the link I posted.  In my mind it was article that explained the difference between catch{...} and catch (Exception) {...}. cant find anything remotely like the post I was dreaming about now - IIRC something changed from .NET 1.1 vs 2 in this area (SEH exceptions?).

Comment: @Alan: the link to the devexpress page is me asking DX to add the same facility to CR (I was doing code tidying and wanted to remove the "(Exception)" bit as I wasnt doing anything other than rethrowing.  I'd have thought that that would be salient enough to gaurd against downvotes!

Comment: @Jon Skeet - if you catch an Exception, you execute all the finally blocks on the stack; is that a good idea when your process is potentially in a corrupted state? Might throw more exceptions - or wreck persistent data. Instead, enlist your logging code on the UnhandledException event in AppDomain.

Comment: More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666645/would-you-ever-not-catch-an-exception-or-throw-an-exception-that-wont-be-caught/666775#666775

Comment: @Charles Bretana: For some reason in my head I wasnt considering them to be equivalent (as covered in my edited version), and I thought the link was to an article covering the difference. Pretty sure I'm with you now tho'...

Comment: @Earwicker: I *suspect* I would want to execute all the finally blocks, yes. I also suspect that would happen even if I didn't have a catch block. Just because the exception is unhandled doesn't mean the stack doesn't get unwound and finally blocks executed. A simple test appears to confirm this.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - depends on the OS, amazingly. On XP, the finally blocks run under some circumstances, on Vista (and recent Servers) they don't, which is the corrected behaviour. Finally blocks executing in response to a bug condition may throw again, or corrupt state, defeating attempts to diagnose.

Comment: You can address the situation on XP by enlisting with UnhandledException to customise how the bug is handled without triggering finally blocks. Post on the CLR team's blog that may be of interest: http://blogs.msdn.com/clrteam/archive/2009/02/05/catch-rethrow-and-filters-why-you-should-care.aspx

Comment: Which in turn prompted this question from me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602066/why-doesnt-c-have-support-for-first-pass-exception-filtering

Comment: Hmm, I just tested it on Vista and it's broken there as well! Andrew Pardoe mentioned that wanted to change it. Anyway - you can customise what happens thanks to the UnhandledException event.

Comment: "AppDomainUnhandledException is thrown after the first pass doesn’t find a handler. The finally blocks don’t run. On Windows 7 and forward... the OS will NOT unwind the stack for you so the finallies won’t run period. On earlier versions of Windows the OS was inconsistent..." - Andrew via email

Comment: @Earwicker, IS all above only true for unhandled exceptions? I.e., if you handle an exception, say 2 steps up the stack, then the finallys between the exception and the handler DO run, right ?