# Avoiding many try...catch blocks

Tags: php

I have various functions in a class. In each function I use try...catch. Is there any way to simplify this? I want to make one error class and it must be accessible from any file in my project. I don't want to use try..catch in each function, rather it should be automatically directed to the Error class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not add the try catch in the function itself but in the page where the function is called.

eg:

```
    try
{
    $faq_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['faq_title']);
    $faq_subtitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['faq_subtitle']);
    $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['desc']);
    $faq_e = new Shopadmin();
    $faq_e->add_faq($faq_title, $faq_subtitle, $desc);
    $feedback = "<div class='succes'>FAQ added succesfully!</div>";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $feedback = "<div class='error'>";
    $feedback .= $e->getMessage();
    $feedback .= "</div>";
}
```

and in my function I check if the query was done succesfully or not, if not I throw a new exception which will be catched and stored into $feedback which I echo out on the main container div.

this way you can call for different functions withouth having to add the try catch in each function

I hope this helps you out

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are using exceptions the wrong way. Exceptions should generally not be thrown to be caught, or at least should not be caught that often. You may want to look at other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=exception+usage) and/or [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666645/would-you-ever-not-catch-an-exception-or-throw-an-exception-that-wont-be-caught) explaining exception usage in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Register a global exception catcher. This function will catch any uncatched exception. You should do it as you do with register_session, that is, in some file which is included in every page, so that it works across the site.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

But note that you cannot recover from such an exception (you can't handle error and continue).

Answer (score -1):

Basically this is a requirement is almost all projects as they get bigger. The solution is to create a Error handling module. You can create one from scratch or use already existing awesome modules like [ELMAH](http://www.raboof.com/projects/Elmah/).

Comment: ELMAH is for ASP.net, we are talking about PHP here

Comment: Oops, my bad, just rush of blood.